# Append data from one file to another windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have 2 files as file1 and file2.

**File1** has data as below.

*$$NewParameter =*

**File2** has data as below

*23/03/2020 14:34:21*

I want **result** as below in file 1

*$$NewParameter = '23/03/2020 14:34:21'*

I have tried below command.

```
type file2.txt >> file1.txt
```

but it gives me expecyed result without single quotes.

Any help regarding this command would be helpful.

Regards,

Mahesh

Comment: Do `File1` and `File2` each contain only one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what your end goal really is, but this is the best I can think of without using a for loop and batch file.

If you want the result on one line

```
set /p one=<file1.txt & set /p two=<file2.txt & echo %one% '%two%'>File1.txt
```

If you want the result on separate lines

```
set /p two=<file2.txt & echo '%two%'>>file1.txt
```